# Wrong output in matching a column values between two csv files using python

Tags: python, csv

I have two `csv` files whose structure is as below:

**Fil1.csv:**

```
66054,14.7065,42.1115
66054,14.7085,42.106
66054,14.7268,42.0937
66054,14.6739,42.125
66054,14.7268,42.0937
66100,14.116,42.3301
66100,14.1405,42.3392
88067,16.431,38.7287
88068,16.5339,38.6899
88068,16.5499,38.685
88068,16.5419,38.6875
87076,16.4795,39.7905
87076,16.4743,39.8161
87100,16.2531,39.2989
87100,16.2944,39.2674
87100,16.3039,39.2709
87052,16.43,39.3449
87053,16.3399,39.3101
87054,16.3171,39.1784
```

**file2.csv:**

```
ABC,66100
"CDF",65125
"123",65125
1234,64100
0123,75025
lmn,85025
abc,88046
"Random",88068
"Raond2",87100
"Raondm3",87100
Raondom4,87054
```

Now what I want to do is for each `row2[1]` in `file2.csv`, find its first occurrence in `row1[0]` and extract the `row1[1]` and `row1[2]` from that row to be inserted along with `row2[0]` and `row2[1]` and write it to another `csv` file. Here is the code I wrote for this:

```
updated_list = []

with open("file1.csv","r") as in_file1, open("file2.csv", "r") as in_file2, open("file3.csv", "w", newline='') as out_file:
    reader1 = csv.reader(in_file1)
    reader2 = csv.reader(in_file2)
    writer_final = csv.writer(out_file)
    for row2 in reader2: #reader2 is for file2

        for row1 in reader1:#reader1 is for file1
            if str(row2[1].strip()) == str(row1[0].strip()):
                print("Found match for {}".format(row2[1]))
                updated_list.append([row2[0],row2[1],row1[1],row1[2]])
                break
            else:
                continue


    writer_final.writerows(updated_geo_list)
```

The above code is able to match some but for a lot of `row2[1]` in `file2.csv`, its not able to match with `row1[0]` in `file1.csv` even though its present. For example in above sample data, the code is not able to match `87100` and `87054` from `file2.csv` to `file1.csv` despite `file1.csv` containing the two values. I though there might be some extra spaces coming in these strings so I used `split()` as well but its still not working. Why is the matching not being done?

Comment: @PatrickArtner file1.csv has about 20000 rows and file2.csv has about 300 rows.

Comment: @PatrickArtner and I can verify items count in each csv reader using `sum(1 for row in reader1)`

Comment: you have dupes in both. you want the shorter file enhanced by the first value in the longer file? keep duplicates in the shorter file?

Comment: wich of (87100,16.2531,39.2989   //  87100,16.2944,39.2674   // 87100,16.3039,39.2709) and "Raond2",87100 // "Raondm3",87100 will be in the third file?

Comment: what happens with stuff only in 2nd file?

Comment: Showing desired output file that should result from the sample input would clear up what you want.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I want to match the first occurrence of 87100 in the file1.csv that's why I was breaking out of loop as soon as I found a match

Answer (score 0):

After running your code and putting `print` statements at few places, it was observed that only for first value of `file2.csv` i.e. "ABC,66100" comparison is made. Rest code just skips through.

That because  [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader)  returns an reader object which is an iterator.
Hence, once you iterate the entire object, it becomes empty.
As a work-around, You need to save your reader as a list in order to iterate it repeatedly.

Modifying line
`reader1 = csv.reader(in_file1)`

to

`reader1 = list(csv.reader(in_file1))`

should give you desired result.

```
import csv
  
updated_list = []

with open("file1.csv","r") as in_file1, open("file2.csv", "r") as in_file2, open("file3.csv", "w", newline='') as out_file:
    reader2 = csv.reader(in_file2)
    reader1 = list(csv.reader(in_file1))
    writer_final = csv.writer(out_file)
    for row2 in reader2:   #reader2 is for file2
        for row1 in reader1:  #reader1 is for file1
            if str(row2[1].strip()) == str(row1[0].strip()):
                updated_list.append([row2[0],row2[1],row1[1],row1[2]])
                break

    writer_final.writerows(updated_list)

cat file3.csv 
ABC,66100,14.116,42.3301
Random,88068,16.5339,38.6899
Raond2,87100,16.2531,39.2989
Raondm3,87100,16.2531,39.2989
Raondom4,87054,16.3171,39.1784
```

**Note**
Converting reader to list may be detrimental if you have large file as it may impact memory. Better option will be to use `openpyxl` or load your data into `pandas` dataframe and manipulate there.

Comment: why does it match ABC twice? Its just once in his 2nd file? Why does it match `Random,88068` three time - its not even once in the first file? Why does it match `Raondm3,87100` with three different values if always the first value from file1 should be used? There something wrong here....

Comment: ah, I used a different version that captured all occurrences. Fixed that  , Answer updated. It should work at your end. Let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment: file objects are streams, once you are past a certain point you can not see it anymore - you would need to put a file into memory to compare all lines of one against the other.

This code reads the smaller file into memory and processes the larger file line-wise.

The first matching line supplicants data for all rows from smaller file, afterwards the row of the smaller file is deleted from memory so it does not match with later ones:

Create files:

```
with open("f1.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("""66054,14.7065,42.1115
66054,14.7085,42.106
66054,14.7268,42.0937
66054,14.6739,42.125
66054,14.7268,42.0937
66100,14.116,42.3301
66100,14.1405,42.3392
88067,16.431,38.7287
88068,16.5339,38.6899
88068,16.5499,38.685
88068,16.5419,38.6875
87076,16.4795,39.7905
87076,16.4743,39.8161
87100,16.2531,39.2989
87100,16.2944,39.2674
87100,16.3039,39.2709
87052,16.43,39.3449
87053,16.3399,39.3101
87054,16.3171,39.1784""")

with open ("f2.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("""ABC,66100
"CDF",65125
"123",65125
1234,64100
0123,75025
lmn,85025
abc,88046
"Random",88068
"Raond2",87100
"Raondm3",87100
Raondom4,87054""")
```

Program

```
import csv

d2 ={}
# smaller file: load in memory
with open("f2.txt") as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f)
    for row in cr:
        # store under same key as list of rows to keep same order and 
        # allow multiple rows with same row[1] value
        k = d2.setdefault(row[1],[])
        k.append(row)

# process larger file 
with open("f1.txt") as f, open("f3.txt","w",newline="") as nf:
    cr = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(nf)
    for row in cr:
        if d2.get(row[0],[]):
            for sl in d2.get(row[0]):
                writer.writerow( (sl + [row[1],row[2]]) )
            # remove from d2 so no reappearing rows will be written
            del d2[row[0]] 

with open("f3.txt") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
ABC,66100,14.116,42.3301
Random,88068,16.5339,38.6899
Raond2,87100,16.2531,39.2989
Raondm3,87100,16.2531,39.2989
Raondom4,87054,16.3171,39.1784
```

Only things from file2 that are matched at all in file1 are put into file3.